# Docker compose doesn't connect two containers

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have two containers that don't connect to each other:
1. I made an image postgres that get data from dump.sql
 here is Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:11.1-alpine
COPY restore_db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY db.sql  /backup/
ENV PGDATA=/data
```

3. Then I created container with docker run --name db -p 5432:5432 db

4.I made a image with app. Dockerfile for app look like:

```
# Set the working directory to /app

WORKDIR /app
# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY build/libs/  /app/

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8085

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME app

# Run app when the container launches
CMD java -jar /app/olympic-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

5. I made a container with run.

then i use docker-compose up with file that looks like:

````
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: db-data
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./pg_data:/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: innovation
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      PGDATA: /data
      restart: always
  web:
    image: app
    container_name: roc
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: db
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
    restart: always
    links:
      - db
```



here is property file:
```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/innovation
 spring.datasource.username=postgres
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
 logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
 logging.level.root=INFO
 spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
 logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

 spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liqubase/db.changelog-master.xml
 spring.liquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/innovation
 spring.liquibase.user=postgres

```

Thet are not able to be connected.

I always got an error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to db:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
````

Comment: look where you defined `localhost:5432` and change it to `db:5432` and make sure that you do not have old images containers , i suggest that you remove all images and containers and build them again

Comment: @LinPy Didn't help

Comment: are your db is running ? `docker ps` and `docker logs DB_CONTINER`?

Comment: Take a look if your 2 containers are in the same docker network.

Comment: Also you can try spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/innovation

Comment: @SpasojePetronijević how to check it? I think containers are not in the same network

Comment: docker network ls will give you the list of networks. Then you can do docker inspect :network_name: and see if in one of the networks both of your containers are present.

Comment: @SpasojePetronijević probably you know how to execute script in docker-compose to get data from dump

Comment: I didn;t understood what you asked me now. :(

Comment: @SpasojePetronijević So I have dump.sql file where I store the data. So I need to get all tables form dump while composing two containers

Comment: You can access your container shell with docker exec -it :container_id: sh. Now shell is opened and you can browse content from your container.

Comment: Does your web container give db time to start before connecting, or retry the connection for a few minutes?

Comment: Note that `restart: always` is set as an environment variable in db, rather than a setting to restart the container, because of your indentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all I dont see any network defined in your Docker files for both containers

So I assume ther are on $project-default network.

```
docker network inspect $project-default
```

will give you list of all containers using default network.

Now coming to the containers, Let's assume DB is **Container 1** (10.1.1.2) and Spring App is **Container 2** (10.1.1.3).

You can get running containers IP by running

```
docker inspect containerName
```

You are exposing `5432` and `8085` port for db and Spring respectively

Inside Spring app container property file `spring.datasource.url`

`localhost:5432 or db:5432` (not sure what is db hostname mapped to) is not accessable as DB is in different container.

You can try `10.1.1.2:5432`

When you are exposing 5432 and 8085 port from Host machine you can access these port.

eg in Docker for Windows it would be  192.168.99.100:5432

but same cant be access from inside container.

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.1.1.2:5432/innov` should work assuming DB is up and running

Comment: The default network for docker-compose is not the "bridge" network. It will create a network named `$project-default`.

Comment: And `db` is the service name which gets a network alias in docker. That is the correct way to connect to another container. Trying to connect to localhost from inside of a container will connect to that container only, and not the host namespace, so you should not be using localhost to connect between containers. Using an IP address is not recommended, that is not portable and will break on updates.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch for the info.  Yes localhost will not work, I am suggesting to connect to containers internal IP if they both share same network.

Comment: If they share the same network, you should use the DNS alias `db`. The IP address will change every time you deploy the project.

Comment: So It finally started but there is no old data. Here is Dockerfile for creating image: 
FROM postgres:11.1-alpine
COPY re store_db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY db.sql  /backup/
ENV PGDATA=/data .   But when I start docker-compose init.sh script doesn't work

Comment: @BMitch May be u can say how to init data form dump during composing 2 images? When I build db image there is script that read sql file and when I create container it works. But during docker-compose init.d script doesn't work.